# Method hospitals does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Hey I am working on a project in which i have defined many to many relation between two tables. I have made a method in model class but whenever i call that method from my controller it gives me error method does not exist. Below is my code of controller and model.

#### Controller

```
if($request->hospitalId != null)
{
    $IdArray = explode(',', $request->hospitalId);
    $doc= DB::table('doctors')->where('doctorId', $request->doctorId)->get();
    foreach ($IdArray as $Id) {
        $doc->hospitals()->attach($Id);
    }
}
```

#### Model

```
public function hospitals()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Hospital');
}
```

#### Pivot Table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateDoctorHospitalTable extends Migration
{
     public function up()
     {
          Schema::create('doctor_hospital', function (Blueprint $table) {
              $table->increments('id');
              $table->string('doctor_id');
              $table->foreign('doctor_id')->references('doctorId')->on('doctors')->onDelete('cascade');
              $table->string('hospital_id');
              $table->foreign('hospital_id')->references('hospitalId')->on('hospitals')->onDelete('cascade');
              $table->timestamps();
         });
     }


     public function down()
     {
         Schema::dropIfExists('doctor_hospital');
     }
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong in it.

Comment: you have created a pivot table for this rite?

Comment: @DhavalChheda yup i have created a pivot table

Comment: can you share that table details

Comment: @DhavalChheda shared

Comment: you should try first() instead of get()

Comment: @DhavalChheda thanx it is not giving the error but i have one more that is the id stored in the pivot table is the one which is by default created when we create migration not the one which i want what should i do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158763/discussion-between-dhaval-chheda-and-nida-akram).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your query because it returns an array, Try to use find method instead:

```
$doc= App\Doctor::find($request->doctorId);
```

Also the `attach` method can accept an array of ids, here is an example:

```
if($request->hospitalId != null)
{
    $IdArray = explode(',', $request->hospitalId);
    $doc= App\Doctor::find($request->doctorId);
    $doc->hospitals()->attach($IdArray);
}
```

Comment: I have done this use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; in my doctor model class but still its giving me the error

Comment: And if attach method accepts array of ids will it create separate record for each id or one

Comment: Yes, It will create a separate records

Comment: The problem was in your query, it returns an array of object

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your relationships from your Eloquent model you need to use the model itself and not the query builder.

Change

```
$doc= DB::table('doctors')->where('doctorId', $request->doctorId)->get();
```

To

```
$doc= Doctor::where('doctorId', $request->doctorId)->get();
```

*Assuming your model is named `Doctor`.*